# cakephpのformhelperラジオボタン機能にて、ラベルの文字数が長いとラジオボタンとラベルの間で改行がされてしまいます。

Tags: php, cakephp

例えば、以下の場合、

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('test', array('label' => true, 
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　'div' => false, 
                                            'type' => 'radio',
                                            'legend'=> false, 
                                            'options' => array('0'=>'123', '1'=>'1234567890'), 
                                            //'before' => '<span>',
                                            //'after' => '</span>',
                                            //'separator' => '</span><span style="white-space: nowrap">'
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　)); ?>
```

LABELのCSS

```
label {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

ラジオボタンを横並びにしているのですが、labelの文字列が長い場合、上記の例ですとradioボタンとlabelの「1234567890」の間で改行されてしまう場合があります。
この場合、radioボタンとlabelをセットで自動改行するようにしたいです。
いい方法はありますでしょうか？
お願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

labelにwidthを付けるのではなく、divをtrueにして、そのdivのwidthを100pxにするのはダメなのでしょうか。